# jQuery autocomplete not sending ajax data

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>    

$('#query').autocomplete({
        source: 'parts_by_partno.php',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#query").val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
            $("#hiddenId").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
        }
    });
```

I'm getting no errors in firebug, but firebug shows this function is not even making a call to the page.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that #query exists when that runs?  If you have it in the header, the dom element likely doesn't exist.

Comment: I moved the autocomplete script link down below the #query field, still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/xJpsL/1/

If I watch the network requests in chrome, it's requesting it properly.  You didn't forget script tags, I assume?  Incidentally, that third javascript file for autocomplete.js does not exist (nor is it needed as autocomplete is part of the jquery ui file).

Comment: Ok it looks like the core script had to be in the hea, and the UI had to be in the body.  It's sending now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the code how I made it work
Use each function and it's good to use with multiple fields too.**

```
$('#query').each(function(i, el) {
    el = $(el);
    el.autocomplete({

        // get source using ajax function
        // If you need to send extra parameters to parts_by_partno.php
        // use data: {}
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'parts_by_partno.php',
                        
                // when you type word in text field
                // el.val() gets a word and ajax sends value of el.val() to server
                data: {id: el.attr('id'), term: el.val()},
              
                success: function(data) {
                    //data - data returned from server
                    response(data);
                },
                dataType:"json"
            })
        }
    });
});
```

**=================== in PHP ===================**

> $sendArray = array();
>
> ```
> $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE name LIKE '".$_GET['term']."%' LIMIT 10"
>
> while($row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)){
>
>   array_push($sendArray, $row['name']);
>
> };
>
> echo json_encode($sendArray);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the code in the ready handler

```
$(function(){
 $('#query').autocomplete({
        source: 'parts_by_partno.php',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#query").val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
            $("#hiddenId").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: have you checked for any javascript errors in firebug or chrome dev tools